# Padding zeros to the end of a string and incrementing them

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string that is up to 10 characters long (EX: 2021-00445) when it's first created in SQL.

I would like to pad it with a trailing dash(-) and three zeros (-000). I also want to have them incremented in the interval of 1, so if it has been incremented once, then the new value of the trailing zeros would be '-001'. Or if it has been incremented 23 times, the value is '-023'. (EX: 2021-00445-000).

How would this be implemented in Toad SQL?

Comment: You refer to 'original value' of 1, 23 or 124, but where are those coming from? What is incrementing, and why? And why does your last example end '-000' rather than '-124' - is that a special case or a mistake? Please edit your question to give representative sample data, fully-explained logic and expected results for that data. I'm not sure if you're trying to modify or format your existing data, or generate extra rows during a query, or add extra rows to a table, or something else. (Also Toad is a client, and which client you use is unlikely to be relevant.)

Comment: How would the increment happen?

Comment: Does your table have less than 1000 records? If not, then how do you account for that with your incrementing? Or are you missing helpful information here where you only increment if the column containing values like `2021-00445` are the same on multiple rows. Lastly, how do you determine order in this table for incrementing? There isn't enough information here to understand or answer.

Comment: Also removing the `toad` tag since your sql client is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a sequence and use something like:

```
your_col := your_col||'-'||LPAD(your_seq.NEXTVAL,3,'0'); /* plsql style*/

UPDATE your_table
   SET your_col = your_col||'-'||LPAD(your_seq.NEXTVAL,3,'0')
 WHERE <your_conditions>;
```

however this is pretty generic since you haven't mentioned when or on what condition the update will happen.